# Rewrite language code into url if missing

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I want to change an existing Magento store to add store/lang codes to the url i.e.

```
http://mystore/en/PRODUCTXYZ.html
http://mystore/de/PRODUCTXYZ.html
```

Old links to *http://mystore/PRODUCTXYZ.html* will now throw a 404 error.

How can I create an Apache url rewrite rule to add a language code if it is missing i.e. rewrite

```
http://mystore/PRODUCTXYZ.html
```

to

```
http://mystore/de/PRODUCTXYZ.html
```

So that old links 301 redirect to the correct product.

I have worked around this with

```
Redirect 301 /PRODUCTXYZ http://mystore/de/PRODUCTXYZ.html
```

But obviously for thousands of products this might not be practical.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can redirect multiple Product.html urls with just 1 line of code using RedirectMatch :

```
RedirectMatch 302 ^/([^/.]+)\.html$ http://example.com/de/$1.html
```

I  used 302 for testing purposes and to avoid browser's cache,
  change 302 to 301 (permanent redirect) when you are sure the redirect is working.